# Kendo UI grid not binding with json data returned from web api controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to bind Kendo UI grid with API modeller created. I checked the web API modeller and it returns data in json format, but when I created html page to display data in Kendo UI grid only grid is displayed and no items.Here is my html code. Someone please point where is doing mistake. Thanks in advance. Im stuck in this 3 days now.

```
</head>
<body>
            <div id="example" class="k-content">
            <div id="grid"></div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
 var crudServiceBaseUrl = "Customer/Get";
                    //alert(crudServiceBaseUrl);
                    dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        transport: {
                            read: {
                                url: "Customer/Get",
                                dataType: "jsonp"
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 20,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "customerID",
                                fields: {
                                    customerID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    customerName: { validation: { required: true} }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    var test = dataSource.data.length;
                    //i tried debugging but data length is 1
                        $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                            dataSource: dataSource,
                            pageable: true,
                            height: 430,
                            toolbar: ["create"],
                            columns: [
                                { field: "customerID", title: "ID", width: "200px" },
                                { field: "customerName", title: "Name", width: "200px" },
                                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "172px"}],
                            editable: "inline"

                    });
                });
            </script>
        </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Mia , did you get solution because i have same problem . If you get answer please tell me how to resolve that ...

Comment: sorry for late reply. Yes I solved it.

Comment: var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: dbAddress + Controller,parameterMap: function (data, operation) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            } pageSize: 12,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        schema: {
            data: "Data",
            total: "Total",
            model: Model,
            errors: "Errors",
            error: function (e) {
                alert("Delete Failed");
                this.cancelChanges();
            }
        }
    });